# Python dataframe exclude rows based on condition not working

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that I am concatenating from dataframes and arrays.
Somehow its inherited the index of the original dataframe - hence I am trying to exclude rows based on one of the columns that should not have missing values.
If I view my dataframe, it shows as this:

```
print(model_data2['is_62p_days_overdue'][0:11])
```

[image]

now, when I run:

```
print(model_data2['is_62p_days_overdue'].where(model_data2['is_62p_days_overdue'] != np.nan)[0:11])
```

I get the exact same output.
And when I run :

```
print(model_data2['is_62p_days_overdue'].where(model_data2['is_62p_days_overdue'] == np.nan)[0:11])
```

[image]

What am I missing? this is driving me nuts!
I've tried resetting the index - but this also does nothing.

Comment: What is your aim? To exclude NaN values?

Comment: Yes.
I took a sub-set of my original data based on date ranges, wich meant I had an interrupted index.
Then I processed individual columsn - mapping functions, transformations etc. Then concatenated a new dataframe based on these individual columns. And somehow, it inherited the index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC:

Instead of this:

```
print(model_data2['is_62p_days_overdue'].where(model_data2['is_62p_days_overdue'] != np.nan)[0:11])
```

try with `loc` accessor and `notna()` method:

```
print(model_data2.loc[model_data2['is_62p_days_overdue'].notna(),'is_62p_days_overdue'][0:11])
```

**Answer to the comment:**

there are 2 reasons of it

1. you can't compare NaN's like that like you do in your method:

```
    model_data2['is_62p_days_overdue'] != np.nan
    
    #this is wrong instead use notna() method
```

2.You are using where method even when you corrected above method it will make that back to NaN:

```
model_data2['is_62p_days_overdue'].where(model_data2['is_62p_days_overdue'].notna())
```

Comment: Thank you

I would like to know why my original code didn't work?

Comment: @GenDemo updated answer...kindly have a look **:)**

Answer (score 1):

see the "# rows you may want to see" in the bottom of my code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# make a dataset

dict={'is_62p_days_overdue':[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, None, None, 0, None, 0, None]}
data=pd.DataFrame(dict)
print(data)


# append numeric 1~10

data=data.append(pd.DataFrame({'is_62p_days_overdue': list(range(1,10+1))}),ignore_index=True)
data

# rows you may want to see

data.loc[~(data.is_62p_days_overdue.isna())]
```

Comment: thank you.
I would like to know why my original code didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

you can use .dropna() to drop the rows with NaN values.
use this:

```
model_data2.dropna(subset = ['is_62p_days_overdue'], inplace = True)
```